# How to jdialog to jpanel thread process

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, jdialog

I have a question. I couldn't solve it for 4 days. I'm making a stopwatch using gui swing in Java. There are 1 jframe and 1 jdialog. I used threads in Jframe. It has a start stop and reset button, it works very well. The problem is; I had to use the jdialog like this (this is the job situation) so when I press the start stop and reset button that I created in jdialog, it triggers the start, stop and reset button in the jframe. There is no problem with triggering either. The main problem is this: While the thread works as it should in the jframe, it does not work when I call it from jdialog. I searched a lot, I made a logic, but I couldn't find it, can anyone help?

Comment: *it does not work* - I don't know what that means. Maybe you need to use a `non modal` JDialog. Read the JDialog API. I will show how to make the dialog non modal when you create the dialog.

Comment: [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html#:~:text=Modal%20dialog%20box%20%E2%80%94%20A%20dialog%20box%20that,closed%2C%20usually%20in%20response%20to%20a%20button%20press.) : _Modeless dialog box — A dialog box that enables you to operate with other windows while this dialog box is shown_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.